# Vaadin browser url doesn't update upon returning to default view

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have the following problem with my project and can't get it working. Example case:

1. MainView class -> Route value ("") => meaning user will see this view class this upon entering the website
2. LoginView class -> Route value ("login") => meaning user will be redirected to the login view.

Problem:

User enters to website, clicks on login button and gets redirected to the LoginView. Browser url is updated to this localhost:808/login.  Then user finishes the login process and clicks on submit button. The following function is fired:

```
this.homepageButton.addClickListener(e -> {
            UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
            ui.navigate(MainView.class);
        });
```

User then is redirected to the main view  and the view is updated yes but the browser url is still staying as "localhost:8080/login". And doesnt update even if i reload the page.

Comment: ui.navigate(".");   did the trick

Comment: I can not reproduce this with vaadin 18 - might be a bug, that was never fixed?

Comment: I'm using version 14, but yeah weird

Comment: Could you provide an example project that shows the problem?

Comment: Currently, I'm at work. I'll prepare such a simple project and upload it to github, then will share you the link, after the work